# Created lifecycle hook issue with VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I have an odd issue, and I don't know if it's an IDE or typo thing? I have the following code, but my IDE is saying the created function is unused and the data isn't loaded from firebase. If I were to type in another created lifecycle hook above it, it doesn't show unused any more, but obviously it complains it's duplicated. What have I done wrong, please?

```
    import db from '@/fb'
    import project from './project.vue'
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                projects: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
          completed(tasks){
              let done = 0;
              for (const task of tasks)
              {
                  if(task.complete === true){
                      done ++;
                  }
              }
              return done;
          }
        },
        created(){
            db.collection('projects').onSnapshot(res => {
                const changes = res.docChanges();
                changes.forEach(change => {
                    if(change.type === 'added'){
                        this.projects.push({
                            ...change.doc.data(),
                            id: change.doc.id
                        })
                    }
                })
            })
        },
        components: {
            appProject: project
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you give me  a stackblitz or something? what's the extension of your file?

Comment: Not sure what a Stackblitz is sorry. It's a .vue file

Comment: @arielb It is Vue.js component `*.vue` file, `<script>` section.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the structure. This is an IDE thing, what IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You should try defining that it is a function. So instead of writing `created()` you should write `created: function()`

```
   import db from '@/fb'
import project from './project.vue'
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            projects: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
      completed(tasks){
          let done = 0;
          for (const task of tasks)
          {
              if(task.complete === true){
                  done ++;
              }
          }
          return done;
      }
    },
    created: function(){
        db.collection('projects').onSnapshot(res => {
            const changes = res.docChanges();
            changes.forEach(change => {
                if(change.type === 'added'){
                    this.projects.push({
                        ...change.doc.data(),
                        id: change.doc.id
                    })
                }
            })
        })
    },
    components: {
        appProject: project
    }
}
```

read the vuejs.org/guide about lifecylce hooks.